# (combinatorial and algebraic) proof that $\sum_{q=1}^n \binom{n}{q}\binom{n-q}{2k-2q}2^{2(k-q)} = \binom{2n}{2k} - \binom{n}{2k}2^{2k}$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients, combinatorial-proofs

I arrived at the following identity throught an attempt at a homework problem: the LHS is my solution; the RHS, the book's one. And *as far I have tested*, they are equivalent.
$$\sum_{q=1}^n \binom{n}{q}\binom{n-q}{2k-2q}2^{2(k-q)} = \binom{2n}{2k} - \binom{n}{2k}2^{2k}$$

The combinatorial meaning of this identity is rather intuitive as per the homework's verbatim:

"Find the number of ways of forming a group of $2k$ people from $n$ couples where $k,n \in \Bbb N$ and $2k \leq n$ so that at least one couple is included in such group".

That being said, the combinatorial meaning of the LHS (and even the RHS) is rather clear: it iterates over $q = \{1,2,...,n\}$ couples, selects $2k-2q$ couples from the remaining $n-q$ and then picks one person from each of these $2k-2q$ couples,  which can be done in $2^{2k-2q}$ ways, to form the group. The RHS does this by composition: removing those groups that do not contain one couple.

However, while I know what the LHS is supposed to do, I don't know how it works. I know that the groups that do not contain 1 couple is given by $\binom{n}{2k}2^{2k}$ (after all, this is the case where $q=0$), but I have little idea as to how the $\binom{2n}{2k}$ term counts the "rest". And I have way fewer ideas about how would I prove this thing algebraically.

**Later edit:** I realized that the $\binom{2n}{2k}$ term simply counts the number of ways of grouping $2k$ people from the overall $2n$ people of the $n$ couples. So ofc all you'd need to do after that is remove those groups that do not contain 1 couple.

Comment: I feel $q$ should start from $1$ in your summation

Comment: Precisely. Fixed it now.

Comment: Moreover, the upper limit should be $k$, as at most $k$ couples can be chosen

Comment: makes sense, but doesn't the summand equals 0 whenever q>k?

Comment: Well the combinatorial proof wasn't very tough to figure out, shall I post an answer with only that?

Comment: I feel like it encompasses a very small part of my question though, as my only combinatorial doubt is really about what the $\binom{2n}{2k}$ term means/does. It might be better fit as a comment, or even as an edit. However, if your combinatorial interpretation is someway distinct from what my question already suggests, maybe it can find its way as an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Algebraic proof**. Your identity is equivalent to (note that the upper limit should be $k$ and the lower limit is $0$ because we moved $\binom{n}{2k}2^{2k}$ to the left hand side):
$$\sum_{q=0}^k \binom{n}{q}\binom{n-q}{2k-2q}2^{2(k-q)} = \binom{2n}{2k}.$$
Now we have that
$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{q=0}^k \binom{n}{q}\binom{n-q}{2k-2q}2^{2(k-q)}&=
\sum_{q=0}^k \binom{n}{q}2^{2(k-q)}[z^{2k-2q}] (1+z)^{n-q} \\
&=[z^{2k}]4^k(1+z)^n\sum_{q\geq 0} \binom{n}{q} \frac{z^{2q}}{4^q(1+z)^{q}} \\
&=[z^{2k}]4^k(1+z)^n\left(1+\frac{z^2}{4(1+z)}\right)^n\\
&=[z^{2k}]4^k\left(1+z+\frac{z^2}{4}\right)^n\\
&=[z^{2k}]4^k\left(1+\frac{z}{2}\right)^{2n}=\binom{2n}{2k}.
\end{align*}$$

Comment: What is that $z$ you have introduced?

Comment: @Ritam_Dasgupta It is a dummy variable. The notation $[z^n]f(z)$ means the coefficient of $z^n$ in the series expansion of $f(z)$ centered at $z=0$.

Comment: @Ritam_Dasgupta This is essentially a solution via _generating functions_; it shows that appropriate generating functions for the two sides are equivalent.

Comment: Thanks, both of you. I got it.

Answer (score 5):

Your equality is known in a somewhat different form. First, let me bring the $\binom{n}{2k}2^{2k}$ subtrahend from the right hand side onto the left, where it neatly fits into the sum as a $q=0$ addend. Thus, your equality becomes
\begin{align}
\sum_{q=0}^n \binom{n}{q}\binom{n-q}{2k-2q}2^{2(k-q)} = \binom{2n}{2k}.
\end{align}
Next, let me generalize this equality by replacing $2k$ by $k$, so it becomes
\begin{align}
\sum_{q=0}^n \binom{n}{q}\binom{n-q}{k-2q}2^{k-2q} = \binom{2n}{k}.
\end{align}
In this form, this is Exercise 2 in [my Fall 2018 Math 5705 homework set #2](http://www.cip.ifi.lmu.de/%7Egrinberg/t/18f/hw2s.pdf), where I give two solutions.

Let me sketch the first solution here (see the above link for details and for the second, purely algebraic solution):

$\newcommand{\set}[1]{\left\{ #1 \right\}}
\newcommand{\abs}[1]{\left| #1 \right|}
\newcommand{\tup}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}$
Imagine that you have $n$ pairs of shoes
$\tup{L_1, R_1}, \tup{L_2, R_2}, \ldots, \tup{L_n, R_n}$,
where the $2n$ shoes $L_1, R_1, L_2, R_2, \ldots, L_n, R_n$
are all distinguishable.
How many ways are there to grab $k$ of these $2n$ shoes -- i.e., to pick a $k$-element subset of the set of all $2n$ shoes?
On the one hand, there are clearly $\dbinom{2n}{k}$ many ways. On the other hand, here is a more complicated way to count these ways: Let's say you are grabbing $q$ complete pairs (i.e., there are $q$ many $i$'s such that you grab both $L_i$ and $R_i$). The number of ways to do so is $\dbinom{n}{q}\dbinom{n-q}{k-2q}2^{k-2q}$ (because there are $\dbinom{n}{q}$ many options for these $q$ complete pairs, then $\dbinom{n-q}{k-2q}$ many options to choose which of the remaining $n-q$ pairs you are grabbing one shoe from, and finally $2^{k-2q}$ options to choose between left and right shoes). Summing this over all possible values of $q$, we conclude that the total number of ways to grab $k$ out of the $2n$ shoes is $\displaystyle \sum_{q=0}^n \binom{n}{q}\binom{n-q}{k-2q}2^{k-2q}$. Now compare this with the first answer, and the identity follows.

I learned this exercise from [Titu Andreescu, Zuming Feng, *A path to combinatorics for undergraduates*, Birkhäuser 2004](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-0-8176-8154-8), where the combinatorial 1st proof appears (as a particular case) as Example 2.11.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a "[snake oil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function#Introducing_a_free_parameter_(snake_oil_method))" proof of the generalization noted by @darijgrinberg:
\begin{align}
\sum_{k \ge 0} \sum_{q=0}^n \binom{n}{q}\binom{n-q}{k-2q}2^{k-2q} z^k
&= \sum_{q=0}^n \binom{n}{q} \sum_{k=2q}^{n+q} \binom{n-q}{k-2q}2^{k-2q} z^k \\
&= \sum_{q=0}^n \binom{n}{q} \sum_{k=0}^{n-q} \binom{n-q}{k}2^k z^{k+2q} \\
&= \sum_{q=0}^n \binom{n}{q} z^{2q} \sum_{k=0}^{n-q} \binom{n-q}{k}(2z)^k \\
&= \sum_{q=0}^n \binom{n}{q} z^{2q} (1+2z)^{n-q} \\
&= (1+2z)^n \sum_{q=0}^n \binom{n}{q} \left(\frac{z^2}{1+2z}\right)^q \\
&= (1+2z)^n \left(1+\frac{z^2}{1+2z}\right)^n \\
&= (1+2z)^n \left(\frac{(1+z)^2}{1+2z}\right)^n \\
&= (1+z)^{2n} \\
&= \sum_{k \ge 0}\binom{2n}{k} z^k
\end{align}
Hence
$$\sum_{q=0}^n \binom{n}{q}\binom{n-q}{k-2q}2^{k-2q} = \binom{2n}{k}.$$

Answer (score 3):

Here is a variation on the theme, a slightly different proof for
enrichment. In seeking to evaluate

$$\sum_{q=0}^k {n\choose q} {n-q\choose 2k-2q} 2^{2k-2q}$$

we observe that (OP notes that $2k\le n$)

$${n\choose q} {n-q\choose 2k-2q} =
\frac{n!}{q! \times (2k-2q)! \times (n+q-2k)!}
= {n\choose 2k-2q} {n-2k+2q\choose q}.$$

This gives

$$\sum_{q=0}^k {n\choose 2q} {n-2q\choose k-q} 2^{2q}
= [z^k] (1+z)^n \sum_{q=0}^k {n\choose 2q}
\frac{z^q}{(1+z)^{2q}} 2^{2q}.$$

Here the coefficient extractor enforces the upper limit of the sum
and we find

$$[z^k] (1+z)^n \sum_{q\ge 0} {n\choose 2q}
\frac{z^q}{(1+z)^{2q}} 2^{2q}
\\ = [z^{2k}] (1+z^2)^n \sum_{q\ge 0} {n\choose 2q}
\frac{z^{2q}}{(1+z^2)^{2q}} 2^{2q}
\\ = [z^{2k}] (1+z^2)^n
\frac{1}{2} \left[ \left(1+\frac{2z}{1+z^2} \right)^n
+ \left(1-\frac{2z}{1+z^2}\right)^n \right]
\\ = [z^{2k}] \frac{1}{2}
\left[ (1+z)^{2n} + (1-z)^{2n}\right]
= \frac{1}{2}
\left[ {2n\choose 2k} + (-1)^{2k} {2n\choose 2k} \right]
= {2n\choose 2k}.$$